# Make Bootstrap Columns Fluid, (Auto Adjustable) now they are stacking on small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid

I don't have reputations please check link but removing spaces

### Problem 1

I am new to responsive and Bootstrap, on fixed width of 980px. I created the 6 columns for 6 icons, in desktop view they look like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/87DyA.jpg but in Mobile view they are stacking, My boss wants that it should change according to view, like in tablet mode it should show 3 icons per row, and in mobile view 2 icons per view. How can I achieve that? http://goo.gl/XkNc39

### Problem 2

My layout is on fixed-width of 980px, but on small view its getting out of area. I am not aware of media queries very much. I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

- Desktop View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgoZS.jpg
- Mobile View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbMpm.jpg (getting out of area)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Bootstrap makes all this very easy.  Read this section to learn how to solve your issues: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

The Bootstrap grid (like most grid systems) always counts to 12. That means that you should calculate how large the column you need to use is. For example: if you want 4 items next to each other you do 12 / 4 = 3, so you use col-..-3.

The classes you should use for your icons are

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
```

The classes explained: on medium devices (col-md-3) items have a width of 3 columns, so 4 items per row. On small devices (col-sm-4) items have a width of 4 columns, so 3 items per row. On extra small devices (col-xs-6) items have a width of 6 columns, so 2 items per row.

I've edited your CodePen and it's working now.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avoqeg

**Problem 2**

It could have something to do with a margin/padding. You could try to take a look in the developers console (right click > inspect element). Or you could reproduce the problem in another CodePen so I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks man, you solved my problem no 1, here is the codepen for problem 2, although it's working fine in codepen i guess. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYPLwb

Comment: You're welcome. It's indeed working fine in the CodePen. I suggest you open your webpage where the error is and right click > inspect element. Than by hovering over your HTML you can see what item pushes the content to the right. Than you select that item and use the 'styles' tab on the right to see what style causes the problem. 
If you can't find it you will need to add more (all of your) css to your CodePen